# TopCoder using the offline visualizer for the LawnMowing chllenge

Tags: java

I can't figure out how to use the offline visualizer for top coder. This is my first time trying to do a topcoder challenge. 
The Lawnmower challenge: 
https://community.topcoder.com/longcontest/?module=ViewProblemStatement&rd=16612&pm=14078

Here is what I am using for a main class to work with the visualizer:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LawnMowing lawnMowing = new LawnMowing();
    int N;
    int turnCost;
    int forwardCost;
    int slopeCost;
    int startCol;
    int startRow;
    //System.out.println("Lawn Mower Begin:");
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     N = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    String[] yard = new String[N];
    for (int i=0; i < N; i++){
     yard[i] = (String) sc.nextLine();
    }
     turnCost = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
     forwardCost = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
     slopeCost = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
     startCol = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
     startRow = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println();
    String ret = lawnMowing.getMoves(yard, turnCost, forwardCost, slopeCost, startCol, startRow);
    System.out.print(ret);
    System.out.flush();


}
```

Here is a basic class I setup for the getMoves() function

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class LawnMowing {

        public String getMoves(String[] yard, int turnCost, int forwardCost, int slopeCost, int startCol, int startRow){
                String leftTurn = "L";
                String rightTurn = "R";
                String straight = "S";

                String moves = "";
                for(int i=0 ; i < 10; i++){
                    moves += leftTurn;
                    moves += straight;
                    moves += rightTurn;
                    moves += straight;
                }
                return moves;

            }

    }
```

Here is my terminal commands:

```
Charless-MacBook-Pro:Documents Charles$ cd workspace
Charless-MacBook-Pro:workspace Charles$ ls
Graphics2       RemoteSystemsTempFiles
LawnMowing      tester.jar
Charless-MacBook-Pro:workspace Charles$ cd LawnMowing
Charless-MacBook-Pro:LawnMowing Charles$ ls
bin src
Charless-MacBook-Pro:LawnMowing Charles$ cd src
Charless-MacBook-Pro:src Charles$ ls
LawnMowing.class    LawnMowingVis.java  Main.java
LawnMowing.java     Main.class      tester.jar
Charless-MacBook-Pro:src Charles$ java -jar tester.jar -exec "java -cp Main"
```

Here's my terminal output:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server   to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.


    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
ERROR: Unexpected error while running your test case.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at LawnMowingVis.runTest(LawnMowingVis.java:438)
    at LawnMowingVis.main(LawnMowingVis.java:524)
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command should be:

```
java -jar tester.jar -exec "java -cp . Main"
```

There is a "." after `-cp`. The `-cp` switch specifies class path, which is the current directory (single period character denotes current directory).